# Marketing Cloud Connector not syncing preferences

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have Marketing Cloud connector setup on an org however the connection doesn't work both ways for the marketing opt in status.

When a subscriber opts out via the Preference Centre, their status is set as Unsubscribed in MC (on the master subscriber table) and their Contact.EmailOptIn field gets updated in Sales Cloud.

However if they re-opt in via preference centre that value doesn't go back into Sales Cloud.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: I've noticed this before too. I believe it is a system limitation, but others may know more.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of reasons this could be happening from experience, based on the following I hope this will help.

- AddMethod - On the All Subs list, check that the AddMethod is salesforce for ths subscriber. If this is not, attribute syncing will not work. This might happen when the first email is sent by a Journey Builder SF Event and not a general Salesforce Send.
- Multi-Org - If multi Org is turned on you will not be able to use this feature reliably.
- Action you are taking - The links which are visible on Sales Cloud can be used and should work. Using the standard UI features from Marketing Cloud should also work. Updating the Opt-in box in Sales Cloud will not work, Updating the subscriber status via ampscript/RMM will not update Sales Cloud (at least as of 1 year ago).

If none of these apply, suggest opening a ticket and updating to community :D

Answer (score 3):

After an extensive back and fourth with Salesforce they have confirmed that actually only Opt-Out data goes back to Sales/Service cloud using the Connector.

In addition to this, the unsubscribe action can only be via the profile centre to sync back. If you manually unsubscribe someone for instance using All Subscribers > Find User > Unsubscribe from All, this will not be synced back.

More information can be found about what is synced back [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_unsubscribes.htm&type=5).